# Pick up point for Shuttle from Terminal 8 JFK

Tags: airport-transfer, jfk

Is there a Ground Transportation Desk at Terminal 8 of JFK? I have booked the goair shuttle as part of a package but the voucher/ticket doesn't tell me where to go for pick up. It may assume( incorrectly) that I will be arriving in Terminal 7 which does have a ground transportation desk.

Answer (score 1):

The terminal map of [JFK Terminal 8](https://www.jfkairport.com/at-airport/airport-maps) indicates the existence of a ground transportation desk.